# How to add repository filter when searching code in azure devops projects with REST API?

Tags: c#, rest, azure-devops

I am not able to add repository filter for Azure DevOps REST API https://almsearch.dev.azure.com.

```
string[] parameterNames = new string[] { "MyRepo" };

JArray jarrayObj = new JArray();

foreach (string parameterName in parameterNames)
{
    jarrayObj.Add(parameterName);
}


string[] parameterNames1 = new string[] { "master" };

JArray jarrayObj1 = new JArray();

foreach (string parameterName in parameterNames1)
{
    jarrayObj1.Add(parameterName);
}

JObject payLoad =   new JObject(
                                 new JProperty("searchText", item),
                                 new JProperty("$top", 133),
                            //   new JProperty("filters", new JObject(new JProperty("Branch", jarrayObj1))
                                 new JProperty("filters", new JObject(new JProperty("Repository", jarrayObj)

                             )));

var newcontent = new StringContent(payLoad.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("https://almsearch.dev.azure.com/myorganization/_apis/search/codesearchresults?api-version=5.1-preview.1", newcontent).Result)
```

Comment: This requires following a link to get the context for the code. Please add any relevant information from the link to the body of your question.

Answer (score 1):

In the Request Body of the API, you can set the filter in the **`filters`** object.

In the **`filters`** object, you can set **Project** filter, **Repository** filter, **Branch** filter, **Path** filter, etc...

For more details, see [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/search/code-search-results/fetch-code-search-results?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#examples).

**[UPDATE]**

When using **`Repository`** filter in the **`filters`** object, you must also add the **`Project`** filter. Otherwise, you will get the status code as **400 Bad Request**.

[image]

Comment: In my original question I have pasted the code for payload creation but this does not seem to be working for repository filter. Can you please let me know what needs to be fixed in the payload code

Comment: Hi @user2386486,
I noticed that when you use the **`Repository`** filter, you do not use the **`Project`** filter. This may be the reason why you get the 400 error.
I have updated my above answer with more details. Please check it.